# How to get the file desciptor of a symbolic link?

Tags: linux, symlink, file-descriptor

I know that I can read a symbolic link with `readlink`, and operate upon it with `llistxattr` etc, but I'm looking to get the file descriptor of it so that I can use it with `flistxattr` etc.

I've also checked manual of `open` and I know `O_NO_FOLLOW` won't open a symbolic link (but will fail so that some applications can be safer).

So is there any way to get the file descriptor of a symbolic link?

Comment: There is a system call named `llistxattr(2)` which lists the extended attributes of a symbolic link.  Maybe you do not need the file descriptor after all but can do your original task using this.

Comment: @Alfe Yes but I know `llistxattr` (first para in my question), and I'm asking how to do it with a fd.

Answer (score 0):

> is there any way to get the file descriptor of a symbolic link?

From the [`symlink(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/symlink.7.html) man page:

> **Obtaining a file descriptor that refers to a symbolic link**
>
> Using the combination of the O_PATH and O_NOFOLLOW flags to open(2)
>   yields a file descriptor that can be passed as the dirfd argument in
>   system calls such as fstatat(2), fchownat(2), fchmodat(2), linkat(2),
>   and readlinkat(2), in order to operate on the symbolic link itself
>   (rather than the file to which it refers).
>
> By default (i.e., if the AT_SYMLINK_FOLLOW flag is not specified), if
>   name_to_handle_at(2) is applied to a symbolic link, it yields a handle
>   for the symbolic link (rather than the file to which it refers).  One
>   can then obtain a file descriptor for the symbolic link (rather than
>   the file to which it refers) by specifying the O_PATH flag in a
>   subsequent call to open_by_handle_at(2).  Again, that file descriptor
>   can be used in the aforementioned system calls to operate on the
>   symbolic link itself.

Comment: But I want to operate on the fd instead of using it as parent directory. Can I use `fchmod`, `fchown` etc on it?